# Number of kanji characters / words I need to learn for N3 level

Tags: kanji

I've been studying Japanese for 2 years. I'm N4 level currently, recently I've had a bit of slump in learning but i think I'm about to go back to learning once again
Can anyone tell me the minimum number of words / kanji characters I need to learn in order to prepare for and accomplish N3 level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Level N3 kanji list is expected to be about 650 kanji in total (or between 300-1000).

A typical list is assembled by taking all the 常用漢字 taught in Japanese high school, grades 1 to 4, and removing those already in levels N4 and N5.

This brings total number of new kanji to be learned to 361. Source: https://jlptstudy.net/N3/?kanji-list